# Portable VirtualBox kernel driver error

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using [PortableVirtualBox](http://www.vbox.me/) for about a year with no problems.
But from two weeks now -without upgrading or updating anything on Virtualbox or anything
related on my PC- after running *any* of my VMs for a while then I cannot start any other
VM, because VB pops up this error

```
---------------------------
VirtualBox - Runtime Error
---------------------------
Cannot access the kernel driver!
Make sure the kernel module has been loaded successfully.
---------------------------
Abort   
---------------------------
```

If I check the VB kernel driver with [ServiWin](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/serviwin.html)
the driver (VBoxDrv) shows up as "Stopping...", but never stops totally.

- I tried with `NET STOP VBoxDrv` (as administrator), but it says that the service is starting or stopping
- Tried the same running as System with `PSEXEC -s`, same result.
- Reinstalled PortableVB and the VB runtimes, no luck
- Try to kill the program using `sc queryex vboxdrv`, but the status is STOP_PENDING and the PID is 0, then I cannot find the process to kill
- Checked memory with `Memtest86` disk with `MHDD`, did a `Prime95` torture test to find posible
  hardware errors: no problems there
- If I reboot the PC, then I can use VB but the problem strikes again after starting a
  couple of VMs (or restarting the same VM after using it for a while)

My configuration:

- PortableVirtualBox 3.3.6.1 (Launcher)
- VirtualBox 4.0.10.r72479
- VB USB and network drivers installed
- Win7 Pro-64 Host
- AMD Athlon II X3 450 / 8 Gby RAM

Any ideas to fix the initial error or force the VB driver to restart without rebooting?